# What is the protruding element on the vertical tail of this Airbus Zero E concept?

Tags: feature-identification, airbus, vertical-stabilizer, hydrogen

The TurboFan concept of Airbus Zero E has a protruding element on the top of its vertical tail, see the image below.

[image: text]

[Image source](https://www.airbus.com/en/newsroom/stories/2022-11-the-cold-heart-that-powers-our-zeroe-aircraft)

Zoomed image

[image: Zoomed image]

Only this variant of the Zero E has it, is it related to the hydrogen turbofan power unit?
It looks like a jettison valve or something like that. I'm wondering because this looks like a drag-sensitive implementation of a release valve.

Comment: Perhaps the boil-off valve? But why does it have to protrude out of the vertical stabilizer?

Comment: They're definitely vents. Prolly because hydrogen discharge would freeze the tip of the surface?